# Use `ref` merely for clarification?

Tags: c#, coding-standards, readability

I wrote a `FillSomeData(ParameterData param, Result res)` method, which populates `res` with some data (just like it says on the label).

`Result` is a class, not a struct, so `FillSomeData` actually affects `res`.

Following a code review, my colleagues insist that I add a `ref` to the method signature (changing it to `FillSomeData(ParameterData param, ref Result res)`), merely in order to make it clear that the method changes `res`.

I believe this is not the intention of the `ref` keyword, and that this is wrong.

What is the common and recommended practice in such situations?

Comment: You're right, it's a dumb approach, because `ref` means changing the variable passed in and not mutating a reference type.

Comment: Stop taking advice from those colleagues. That said, taking a parameter which is intended to be modified to indicate a result is a bad practice. Redesign your method so that it either (1) returns a value, or (2) produces a side effect, but NOT BOTH. Use *exceptions* in the latter case to indicate a failure.

Comment: Keep in mind that your method isn't changing res at all. It is changing the _contents_ of the object that res _points to_, so it keeps its previous value (a memory address to an specific object of type "Result") no matter what you do inside the method.  It's a completely different matter. Your colleagues probably shouldn't be allowed near C# code until they grasp the difference.

Comment: I don't think the coworkers in question need to be written off entirely. They are trying to clarify that the method causes a side effect that is best avoided, but just sort of part of the OOP world. I agree with Doc Brown that the best approach is the just try to make the method name as clear as possible though.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**No.**

For anyone who has understood what the `ref` keyword means, this obfuscates what the method really does. The better alternative is to pick a more descriptive name for such a method like

```
 FillSomeDataIntoResult(ParameterData param, Result res)
```

You can also try to avoid the usage of `ref` at all, by changing your code in a way it will allow to write

```
 Result res=CreateResult(param)
```

or

```
 res.SomeData=CreateSomeData(param)
```

or

```
 res.InitSomeData(CreateSomeData(param))
```

Of course, to make the latter a possible solution, one might need to restructure the fill code and/or the `Result` class, and sometimes that does not seem to be worth it.

Comment: Correct. Also, I believe for the OPs use case, the correct keyword would actually be `out` in any case, which would be likely used as `public bool FillSomeDataIntoResult(ParameterData data, out Result res){}`, so that it's a 'true' return value if res was actually filled/modified.  I don't think that's a *great* API, but it's what the `out` parameter keyword was intended for.

Comment: @Paul: for the OPs use case, `out` would be even more wrong than `ref`, since his intention is to fill (or maybe partially fill) an **existing** object. With `out` that is simply not possible.

Comment: Ah! my mistake.  I missed that it was updating an already initialized object.  Good point.